# How to say: but there are some differences in the translation

Tags: traduction

I want to say this sentence in French:

> but there are some differences in the translation

Is it:
1. Mais, il y a des différents dans la traduction
2. Mais, il y a quelques différents de traduction

Or both are wrong? Please help me to correct this sentence. Sorry for my broken French, je suis une débutante :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 or 2 can be used, but you did a error with different, it’s not the adjective that is used there but the noun, so it should be « différences »

> Mais, il y a des *différences* dans la traduction
>   Mais, il y a quelques *différences* de traduction

To use « différent » I would more see a sentence like that;

« mais, il y a des mots différents dans la traduction »

Comment: Thank you for the correction :) It helps a lot!!

Comment: I would remove the comma because the English sentence hasn't any.

Comment: thank you @jilliagre !